# How Remove <td> without CLASS using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone give an idea on how to remove `<td>` inside  `<body>` without CLASS "response" usig Jquery ? Please see may HTML Code below for sample .

CODE:

```
<table id="tblFruit" class=" table striped bordered hovered">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Fruit Name</th>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th>Kilos</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="mybasket">
            <tr>
                <td class="response">Apple</td>
                <td>Apple</td>
                <td class="response">Red</td>
                <td>Red</td>
                <td class="response">5 kilos</td>
                <td>5 kilos</td>
                <td class="response">110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you please add some more details to your question.?? Could not understand it. what does `"" inside ""` mean?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy . I Want to remove all TD Element inside BODY element without Class "responce"

Comment: what generates this HTML markup? This is the question  you should ask to yourself instead of trying to fix it client side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('td').not('.response').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `:odd` selector at this context to remove the `td` elements with out using the class,

```
$('#mybasket > tr > td:odd').remove();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2kcrxLr4/1/)

Comment: can add disply property

Answer (score 0):

add css prperty in code

you can add inline css also

```
<td class="response" style="display:none">Red</td>
                <td>Red</td>
```

or make class

```
.table td{
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td:not(.response)').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all guys for idea, i found the answer

```
$('#bodyInfoMilestone tr > td').not('.response').remove();
```